# How to invoke R installed on a home cluster

Tags: r, ssh

I would like to use R-3.2.0 installed in my home on cluster. By default R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22) is installed for all users of the cluster but I have some problems with some libraries.

How can I open my "locally" installed R?

Comment: Did you try `~/R-3.2.0/bin/R`  ?

Comment: Yes but it gives me the following error: "can't open ~/R-3.3.2/etc/ldpaths.

Comment: It seems very odd that R-3.2.0 is looking for R-3.3.2 load paths.